# How to remove documents stored on Evince's "home page"?

Tags: pdf, gnome, evince

Is there a way to remove certain documents from the front page of Evince? Or reset the entire thing back to zero and have no documents show up until I pull one up again?

This page is what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[How do I clear Evince's "recent documents" list?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634461/how-do-i-clear-evinces-recent-documents-list)
has two answers:

- Remove the list of recent files from evince and other gnome
  applications:
  `rm ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`
  (I suggest keeping a backup)
- Clear the shared GNOME recent document list in
  *Settings > Privacy > Usage & History*.

More details are to be found in this post.

Comment: I have tried the second and it appears to only affect the Nautilus recent menu Evince accesses when the Open button is pressed, not the main page that stores document thumbnails.